# Move from SQL Server CE to SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, sql-server-express

I just wrote a large program using SQL Server Express and was very happy, the difficulty is that it is difficult for customers to install SQL Server to test the program out.

I looked into SQL Server CE and it looks great for smaller clients and trial software. However SQL Server CE uses `System.Data.SqlCeServer` and not `System.Data.SqlClient`

Is there a way to make an application that uses SQL Server CE and then if desired the client can upgrade to SQL Server Express?

Comment: I would look for a simpler way (for the end user) to get the SQL Server Express database installed. How are you doing it currently?

Comment: As Beth says, there is no easy upgrade path. You may want to have a look at SQL 2012 localdb though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh230763.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No, they're different platforms.  CE is for the Compact Edition, so it's intended to be used on sometimes disconnected devices with limited resources compared to a SQL Server.  CE should have a subset of Express' functions.